# How to handle HTTP error in the client side?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, http, error-handling

What is the best way to handle **HTTP** errors (404, 503, etc.) when submitting a crucial `data` on the server?

Possible solutions I came up with:

- having the `data` stored in the `session` for later
  submission (data is lost if session expired)
- have the `data` downloaded by the user and manually submit it again
- is it possible to store the `data` as cookie?

Comment: You might consider localStorage for storing data

Comment: I'd say having the data stored in the session for later submission (data is lost if session expired) is the best option to handle it

Comment: the second solution is the best :))) if you want to avoid users on your site :))))

Comment: the question is misleading

Comment: @E.Sundin seems like this is the best, storing data inside a web database. will try to do some research and ill update

Comment: Consider `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can store data at cookie.

Or you can store data by ajax before your 'real' data submit.

like this ..

```
function doSubmit() {

    // It will store the crucial data at server side.
    try {
        $.ajax({
           ...
           url : /temporary/storeData.do,
           data : {
                      // Your crucial data will be located here.
                  },
           ...
        });
    } catch (e) {
        // Error Handling for '$.ajax.error'.
        return;
    }

    // It's your real submit.
    document.aform.submit();
}
```